# Django template update without refreshing

Tags: django, django-templates

I am trying to print sensor reading coming from esp8266 to Django's database in a template. I need the data to be shown in the template without refreshing the page to get new values.
This the views, urls and the template codes

```
class SensorReading(ListView):
    model = Sensor
    template_name = "sensor.html"
```

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", index, name="index"),
    path("/reading", SensorReading.as_view(), name="reading"),
]
```

```
<body>
    <ul>
      {%for reading in object_list reversed%}
      <li><p>{{reading.SensorType}}</p></li>
      <li><p>{{reading.Reading}}</p></li>
      <li><p>{{reading.Time}}</p></li>
      {%endfor%}
    </ul>
```

View that receives readings from sensor

```
@csrf_exempt
def index(request):
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        type = data.get("sensorType", None)
        reading = data.get("reading", None)
        print(type)
        print(reading)
        sensor = Sensor()
        sensor.SensorType = type
        sensor.Reading = reading
        sensor.save()
```

Comment: I updated the question and added the function view which receives sensor reading. I found answers that uses Ajax but I have no idea about it. would be nice if you have any idea where to start

Comment: I researched it a bit more. The real-time requirement of your project led me to the conclusion that Django Channels might be what you need. It requires learning a little about websockets. I would look more into [real python](https://realpython.com/getting-started-with-django-channels/) and maybe do the [chat tutorial](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/index.html), then try to apply it to your project. Sorry, I've never used Django Channels.

Comment: I will look at it. thanks for your help